# RSA python publickey using pyCrypto

Tags: python, gnupg, pycrypto

How to load a RSA public key file into a pyCrypto publickey object in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSA Class has an [importKey](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/apidoc/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#importKey) method for this:

> importKey(externKey)   Import an RSA
>   key (public or private half).
>
> externKey: the RSA key to import,
>   encoded as a string. The key can be in
>   DER (PKCS#1) or in unencrypted PEM
>   format (RFC1421).

Comment: I cannot find the above mentioned method. This must be added in newer versions. Is there a way to do the imports and exports using version 2.1? Apparently the importKey method was added in 2.2 version.

Comment: @banx You'll need to upgrade to 2.3, because the `importKey` method uses other new classes to do the import of the key. I don't see any easy way to backport unfortunately.