# Python - How do I implement readers/writers in a Bulletin Board Pattern with encrypted posts

Tags: python, encryption

I have the following classes:

```
class MessageBoard:

    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []
        self.readers = {}

    def post(self, message):
        self.messages.append(message)

    def register_reader(self, reader):
        self.readers[reader.name] = reader.public_key


class Reader:

    def __init__(self, name, public_key, private_key):
        self.name = name
        self.public_key = public_key
        self.private_key = private_key

    def register_on_board(self, board):
        board.register_reader(self)

    def read(self, message):
        return self._decrypt(message)

    def _decrypt(self, message):
        #Unknown method using private_key


class Writer:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, message, board, intended_reader_name):
        public_key = board.readers[intended_reader_name]
        board.post(self._encrypt(message, public_key))

    def _encrypt(self, message, key_to_use):
        #Unknown method using public_key
```

How do I implement the public key / private key generation and the use of them in `Writer()._encrypt` and `Reader()._decrypt`?

Comment: So the keys are centrally generated and stored? That seems insecure to me.

Comment: The public keys are centrally stored on the message board for encryption purposes. No need to pass the public key / private key in at instantiation ... the Reader could generate them itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this (generate and store private keys centrally), see [these instructions](http://www.laurentluce.com/?p=280) - relevant code snippet below for reference:

```
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>> random_generator = Random.new().read
>>> private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
>>> public_key = private_key.publickey()
>>> enc_data = public_key.encrypt('abcdefgh', 32)
>>> private_key.decrypt(enc_data)
'abcdefgh'
```

However, please bear in mind that *unless I'm mistaken about the purpose of your application* this is **an insecure way of doing this**.

I'm assuming that the `Reader` does not actually reside in the same system as the `Writer` - if they do, I see no reason whatsoever why to use `PKI` (asymmetric crypto) in any case when a simple symmetric AES crypto would suffice.

If my assumption is correct, the `Reader`should generate the private key as described above, and *only* pass the public key to the `Writer` and [import the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011666/rsa-python-publickey-using-pycrypto) using `RSA.importKey` - unfortunately you need `pyCrypto >= 2.1` for this